# Метки с собственной картинкой

Tags: яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

Сайт на ВП, дано: карта яндекса с проставленными уже горой меток и вставленная на сайт.
Необходимо реализовать: оставить те же метки, но заменить картинку самих меток на свою.
Я не программист и мне тяжело разобраться с тем, что написано в документах самого яндекса, к сожалению.
Буду благодарен за любую подсказку, как это можно сделать!

Answer (score 0):

```
var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([latitude, longitude], {
    // информация о метке
}, {
    iconLayout: 'default#image',
    iconImageHref: 'http://your-site.com/path-to-your-image.jpg', // здесь будет ссылка на ваше изображение
    iconImageSize: [30, 42], // размеры вашего изображения
    iconImageOffset: [-3, -42] // сдвиг изображения, чтобы точка метки совпадала с нужным местом на картинке
});
```

В опциях метки (placemark options) вы сможете указать свое изображение, которое будет использоваться в качестве метки.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, но куда нужно вставить этот код, чтобы все получилось?

Comment: И можно ли сделать эту картинку глобальную, для все карты и для всех меток?

Comment: @PavelS. Послушай, это сайт где собирают занания и разбирают сложные кейсы в программирвоании. Я бы помог вам с удовольствием, но не тут. Можете обраться к знакомым разработчикам или посмпрашивать в ощих чатах. Это не сложная задача, почти любой разработчик с легкостью с этим спарвится.